# How to read what is inside of table from PDF file using .net console app(C#)

Tags: c#, .net, console-application

I have PDF file over 30+ pages and i have some tables in, i have problem of reading cell and columns inside of table because my table start at page 4 (example ) and end at page 7 (example ). It depends of input PDF file where table will start and end. Is there any solution how i can get all values from every cell over one row. But there is a catch when table breaks because of new page it create new row if it ends on row before and cut it at half. Any help would be nice.I can use whatever library i want (paid/ not paid preferably). Project is based on .net 8 but I can use older version too if there is a better solution.

I tried to read PDF file using iTextSharp but it doesen't work well because when iTextSharp start reading the file it reads it from left to right and concatenate string from every cell instead of reading first cell, than go to next and so on.

Comment: PDF has no tables. A PDF file isn't a document, it's a file containing print commands (Postscript). What you see as a table is vertical and horizontal lines with text in specific locations. Nothing says the text parts are added horizontally either. I've seen PDF files where trying to select a row results in selecting the first row. Various libraries and utilities try to detect table and data based on the coordinates of the lines or the location of the text BUT sometimes that fails and they have to resort to OCR. Everything depends on how the PDF file was created

Comment: `start at page 4 (example) and end at page 7 (example)` that's another problem. Since it's not a document, a PDF files contains the Postscript commands for specific precalculated pages. You don't have a "table" that spans 4 pages, you have 4 "tables" in 4 pages. Once again, iText and other libraries can try to handle this but ...